# Why does jQuery not provide a .firstChild method?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I have seen plenty of discussion regarding the fastest way to select a first child element using jQuery.  As can be expected, the native DOM firstChild property is much faster than using a jQuery selector or combination of selectors -- see http://jsperf.com/jquery-first-child-selection-performance/6.  This is not usually a problem -- either it's being used in a place where performance is not a big deal, or it's easy enough to just access the DOM element and use its .firstChild property.  However, there are a couple problems with this:

- firstChild could return a text or comment node, rather than an element, as a jQuery selector would return
- If I need to select the first child of multiple elements, I must either use a slow selector, or go to a lot of extra work iterating over DOM elements, adding them to a collection, then putting them back into a jQuery object.

It seems to me that the cost of adding a firstChild method to the core jQuery library would be far smaller than the benefits.  I took my own shot at creating such a method for my own use:

```
$.fn.firstChild = function() {
    var ret = [];

    this.each(function() {
        var el = this.firstChild;

        //the DOM firstChild property could return a text node or comment instead of an element
        while (el && el.nodeType != 1)
            el = el.nextSibling;

        if (el) ret.push(el);
    });

    //maintain jQuery chaining and end() functionality
    return this.pushStack(ret);
};
```

In the tests I created at http://jsperf.com/jquery-multiple-first-child-selection, this function performs more than five times faster than any other option.  The tests are based on the tests mentioned above, but are selecting the first children of multiple elements, rather than a single element.

Is there something I am missing?  A technique that I should be using?  Or is this an issue than one should never worry about?  Is there a reason to not include a function like this in jQuery?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *"Why does jQuery not provide a .firstChild method?"*

Feature creep, most likely.

It can be accomplished with other methods as you stated, and if performance is a concern, you can extend jQuery for that specific need as you've done.

---

You can improve performance in your code a little more...

```
$.fn.firstChild = function () {
    var ret = [];
    // use a for loop
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        var this_el = this[i],
            el = this_el.firstElementChild; // try firstElementChild first
        if (!el) {
            el = this_el.firstChild;
            while (el && el.nodeType != 1)
                el = el.nextSibling;
        }
        if (el) ret.push(el);
    }
    //maintain jQuery chaining and end() functionality
    return this.pushStack(ret);
};
```

Comment: +1, I did not know about firstElementChild.  For the curious, I found a browser support chart here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_traversal.html

Comment: I should also mention that I added the improved firstChild function to the jsperf test cases linked above.

Comment: People got mad of me because of you... :) check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129306/173320) out.

Answer (score 0):

For the single element cases you can use the

```
$('.test > eq(0)')
```

which seems to almost match yours in speed..

http://jsperf.com/jquery-multiple-first-child-selection/2

Comment: It's fast because it's an invalid selector, so it isn't actually doing any DOM selection. The valid selector is `:eq(0)`, which is specific to Sizzle, and will be slow, especially considering that without any other selector before the `:`, you're effectively doing `*:eq(0)`, which will select all elements in the DOM, see if they're at index `0`, then see if their parent has `.test`.

Comment: @amnotiam lol .. damn i missed that... and i thought i was on to something and was trying to improve on it ... *chuckle*.  Thanks for the heads-up.